# How to get device console in Xcode6?

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I am exploring iOS8 beta. I couldn't find the device console logs in "Window->Devices->MyiPad". Can someone tell me how I can get the console logs?

Answer (score 149):

You are on the right way. Just click on the small arrows down (see the image)and it will show you the Logs.

[image]

Comment: When I look there all I see is the text `========================
ASL is here to serve you` and nothing more.  Perhaps it's a beta thing.

Comment: @Perry I think you need some adding, It will be fixed.

Comment: It turns out if I disconnect and reconnect the phone enough times the console output will appear.  How many times?  About 8!  A beta bug I'm sure.

Comment: BTW: This is still present in Xcode 6.0.1. It also took me ages to find out how to give the console more space. The line to drag to make it bigger is invisible and about 0.5cm above the small arrow to open the console.

Comment: @wrtsprt , yeah but in Mac software its always like that ;) . You must think that everything is movable, and try :)

Comment: App Store Review Guide point 10.6: "Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected"

Answer (score 25):

Here's an updated image of josef's answer with Xcode 7.3.1

1) Plug in the device and open Xcode

2) Choose Window -> Devices from the menu bar

3) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device

4) To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel

5) Click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file

[image]

Answer (score 21):

There's a small arrow pointing down under 'Installed Apps'.  They've made it almost impossible to find on your own...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9

Window -> Devices and Simulators[image]

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14.2
Click on connected device -> Add additional simulators -> click device tab