# iOS 8 Read console logs from user devices without installing Xcode

Tags: ios, logging, console, ios8

Any ideas how to get console logs from a user device running iOS 8?

Previous methods, including the iPhone Configuration Utility, do not seem to work with iOS 8 - the latter just doesn't show anything for the console. The older related iOS apps stopped working since iOS 7.

Installing Xcode is not an option, since the user is most likely running Windows, and in any case will not tolerate a multi-GB download and install.

Comment: Get iSyslog: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/isyslog-system-monitoring/id468155763?mt=8
Works also on iOS7 and iOS8. Runs natively on any device (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad). No jailbreaking required.

Comment: Note: It doesn't support iOS 9. The updated description of iSyslog says: "Please note that iSyslog no longer works on iOS9. Get the app only if your device is running prior versions of iOS."

Answer (score 8):

We have an other option, which is, by installing itools and follow the below navigation where you can see the console logs.

Connect Your device to Windows. click on itools->Under iPhone->>Advanced->System logs.

Install itools from this location http://itools-for-windows.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Here is normal link without softonic crap: http://dl2.itools.hk/dl/iTools0925E.zip, and homepage: http://itools2014.com/ . So funny thing this IS NOT official Apple software. So there is no 100% it will be work in the future. (Thank you apple, you don't even care as always)

Answer (score 5):

[iTools](http://itools2014.com/)

- To get real time iOS system logs on windows machine.

Note: Based on iOS / Xcode / iTunes (overall Apple) updates, this information is subject to change. With current iOS version 8.1.3, the [iTools](http://itools2014.com/) software version 3.1.7.6 works great.

1. Open iTools.
2. Connect your iDevice.
3. In the left pane under your device, choose 'Advanced'.
4. Click on 'System Logs'.

You'll get real time system logs just as Console log in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS8 update iPhone Configuration Utility cannot get the logs. from a tutorial in testflight website, they say specifically for iOS 8 devices use xCode. So I guess you are out of luck.

Comment: Where can we see the console logs of an iOS device in Xcode 6? The Logs option under Xcode -> Windows -> Device shows the crash logs but not console logs.

Comment: No worries.. Found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484817/how-to-get-device-console-in-xcode6