# App installation failed: Unknown Error Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

My app runs fine in the simulator, but when I try to install it on my iPhone it says

> App installation failed: An unknown error has occurred.

I opened my device logs and got this:

> Nov 12 21:17:19 Isaacs-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[5853] : LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder  Raritea.FSS-App <(null) *Not found in database*>
>   Nov 12 21:17:19 Isaacs-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[5853] : LaunchServices: Not creating progress for  Raritea.FSS-App <(null) *Not found in database*> since it is not a placeholder.
>   Nov 12 21:17:19 Isaacs-iPhone installd[4549] : 0x16e1bb000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/FSS App.app" type Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 5853)
>   Nov 12 21:17:19 Isaacs-iPhone installd[4549] : 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing 
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone profiled[4644] : (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone profiled[4644] : (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone securityd[4588] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone securityd[4588] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone installd[4549] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone profiled[4644] : (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone profiled[4644] : (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone installd[4549] : unrecognized status -67049 from codesigning library
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone installd[4549] : 0x16e12f000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 142: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FvOJz0/extracted/FSS App.app/PlugIns/QuickSched.appex : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone installd[4549] : 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[5853] : 0x16e087000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FvOJz0/extracted/FSS App.app/PlugIns/QuickSched.appex : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)" UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620415, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=142, FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FvOJz0/extracted/FSS App.app/PlugIns/QuickSched.appex : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[5853] : ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
>   Nov 12 21:17:20 Isaacs-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[5853] : __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:274: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/FSS%20App.app/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620415, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FvOJz0/extracted/FSS App.app/PlugIns/QuickSched.appex : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}

Comment: Tried Clean & Re-build?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line in the device logs stood out to me, and hopefully you saw it too:

> Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FvOJz0/extracted/FSS App.app/PlugIns/QuickSched.appex

This is saying that (although Xcode thought everything was OK at build time), your device rejected the code signature of your app extension.

There are a few solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25999433/2446155), but in my personal experience, this issue can only be fixed by tinkering with the code signing settings for your app and app extension. Make sure that the app and app extension are being signed with the same certificate (although likely different provisioning profiles).

As others have recommended, I've also been able to fix this by running the `Clean` action in Xcode for the project, and also by [deleting the derived data directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6). But I have not always been successful with this.

Comment: Guys I Just Cleaned the project and it worked. Upvoted this answer to help others. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me before. I had to navigate to derived data and delete it. Restart Xcode. Solved the issue for me. You may want to restart your computer as well.

Comment: That was it for me. Yet another bizarre XCode error.

Answer (score 8):

I have had luck by disconnecting my iPhone from my mac, and then Analyzing (Shift + Command + B or Product -> Analyze).

After that I plugged my iPhone back in and did a clean (Command + k) and then ran! Worked!

Comment: I got it working by using Analyze without using Clean afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a long time on this issue. Doing the following in XCode finally resolved it for me. Some of this is mentioned already, but no.4 finally resolved it for me.

1. Product > Clean Build Folder (Cmd+Shift+K)
2. Project > Target (Project) > Build Settings, and check if path of "Info.plist" file is same as the path you get if you right click on the file > Show file inspector > location="Relative to Project"
3. Disconnect Phone & restart laptop & restart phone
4. Project > Target (Project) > Build Settings, and ensure "Excluded Architectures" is empty. Mine had arm64 in excluded architectures for some reason.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with an app without app extension on XCode 10.2.1.

None of the solutions worked for me, so I deleted the XCode target and recreated it with the same files and settings. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try it :

> Xcode-> Preferences->Locations->Derived Data-> Delete it...

It will clean your project,
Try to restart your device.
Then build the app on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, in device log it said that code signing failed for my app extension ....appex. I went to my **App Target -> Build phases -> Embed App Extensions** and checked **Copy only when installing**, after that I could install the app on the phone.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me :

1) Product > Archive (From Xcode)

2) Export iPa

3) Install this iPa from iTunes or Diawi.