# iOS8 Enterprise application download link click nothing happen in Safari?

Tags: ios, ios8, in-house-distribution

hi i create a enterprise application and i upload plist and html file in dropbox but click in safari nothing happen

my plist

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!-- array of downloads. -->
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>

            <!-- an array of assets to download -->
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>

                <!-- software-package: the ipa to install. -->
                <dict>

                    <!-- required.  the asset kind. -->
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>



                    <!-- required.  the URL of the file to download. -->
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ug5heuw6xknye4v/xx.ipa</string>
                </dict>

                <!-- display-image: the icon to display during download. -->
                <dict>

                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>

                    <!-- optional. icon needs shine effect applied. -->
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>

                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/70htok1w98emruq/AppIcon57x57.png</string>
                </dict>

                <!-- full-size-image: the large 512Ã—512 icon used by iTunes. -->
                <dict>

                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>

                    <!-- optional.  one md5 hash for the entire file. -->
                    <key>md5</key>
                    <string>61fa64bb7a7cae5a46bfb45821ac8bba</string>

                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>

                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/yh40pw50m5wa4mf/iTunesArtwork.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>

            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>

                <!-- required -->
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.company.product</string>

                <!-- optional (software only) -->
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>

                <!-- required.  the download kind. -->
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>

                <!-- optional. displayed during download; -->
                <!-- typically company name -->
                <key>subtitle</key>
                <string>Apple</string>

                <!-- required.  the title to display during the download. -->
                <key>title</key>
                <string>product name</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

and my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
<a href="itms-services://?action-download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4o5z1ha7d3sw9dm/xxx.plist">
click this link to install in DropBox
</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

i change http to https, create new certificate to build new ipa,change bundle identifier in distribution plist but in iPad device i click it nothing happens.how to solve that or if any thing new in ios8 change in enterprise app

Answer (score 3):

Starting in iOS 8, opening an itms-services link will not close Safari. Have you tried hitting the home button and seeing if the app has been installed?

If not, it may be another issue with iOS8 where is is somehow caching a list of installed bundle ids and that cache is nor updated properly when an app installed prior to iOS8 is uninstalled in iOS 8.  In order to see if this is the problem, you'll want to check the device console when you try to do the install.  The console can be found by plugging the device into your Mac, opening Devices in Xcode, and finding the device on the left.  The console can be expanded using the arrow at the bottom left (see this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24714865/3708242).

If this is your problem, you can fix it by either reinstalling iOS 8 from scratch (annoying, but the best solution with the fewest problems), or by changing the bundle id in the .plist file referenced in the itms-services link.  More details about that fix here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948839/3708242

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with changing the bundle-identifier, the bundle-version and renaming the plist file.

All of it was needed to solve my issue. Only changing the bundle didn't do the trick for me...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the only thing I could think of is, that your server doesn't support the required MIME types:

application/octet-stream ipa

text/xml plist

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other responses you should make sure that your .ipa filename does not contain any spaces. Even if you urlencode thoses sp