# xCode device logs not populating after application crash

Tags: ios, xcode, coronasdk, crash-reports

I'm getting a crash on my iPad 2 when building my Corona SDK app with a distribution profile, and putting it on my device via a USB cable. I'm testing a bug that happens when the internet is not connected (not sure if relevant). When the app crashes, the devices window's output stream states that it's storing a crash report (http://pastebin.com/Qa3BeaJ2), but then the crash never shows up when I push the "view device logs" button. When I push that button, I get an error message. Is resolving this the secret to getting my crashes to show up in the device logs?

> Jul 28 13:41:17 JackSpicer crash_mover[6180] : (Error)
>   NPSLogging:  Failed to
>   resolve pairing ID ((null)) or data store ((null)) for active device

Thanks!

UPDATE: It's now 10 PM. I've been checking the device logs throughout the day...and I just NOW got an update from 5:46 PM. What the hell? It's extremely short, and says:

```
Incident Identifier: 2481ECB9-EB67-4580-8F50-0F3BC9DEC466
CrashReporter Key:   cda9dbf37d5d3acf21765f20407ce60ad9f7b70a
Date: 2015-07-28 17:46:26 +0800
Reset count: 0
Boot failure count: 1
Boot faults: 
Boot stage: 255
Boot app: 2681261667
```

Comment: have you try restarting your device?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately with no luck. I just two minutes ago I got a crash from 5 hours ago, though, strangely enough. It's extremely short. See the update in my question.

Comment: Referencing from your update. that is not an actual crash log. see if this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484817/how-to-get-device-console-in-xcode6 helps you.

Comment: @JLONG I don't really understand what's in that link that can help me -- I've tried plugging and unplugging the iPad, and I'm not looking for the console logs. I know where those are, and I see them. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem

Answer (score 9):

OK, I was able to populate my crash. Here's how I did it:

- Synced the device with iTunes
- Opened ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/< Device Name >
- Found a folder named Retired (no idea why or what this is)
- Inside was my crash log named blah.blah.beta
- Added a .crash extension
- Dragged it into Xcode's View Device Logs window

Comment: Holy crap! It worked. Once. Then I had to go through the whole process again when I wanted to see a new crash log. Is there any way to get it to auto-populate all the time?

Maybe it happened because I added a space into my device name? There were two folders in my MobileDevice folder -- one of them like MyDevice, the other like My Device. What do you think?