# Xcode isn't showing recent crash logs

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-log

On my phone I set *Share With App Developers* to `On`.

*Settings > Privacy > Analytics > Share With App Developers > On*

I printed a nil value to force a crash:

```
var x: String?
print(x!)
```

I saw the crash in the console but when I went to:

```
Window > Device and Simulators > myPhone > myApp's name > View Device Logs > Process > myApp's name
```

I only see my app's old crashes from Nov 2017 (nothing before or after). It's not showing any current crashes from my app but it shows all the current crashes from all my other apps like YouTube, Slack, Stack Overflow etc. The one where I just printed a nil value an hour ago isn't even appearing.

[image]

In Xcode I navigated to Crashes but it says No Crash Logs:

*Windows > Organizer > Crashes > App Store > releaseInAppStore* but nada

**Why aren't my recent crash logs appearing?**

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668287/xcode-device-logs-not-populating-after-application-crash

Comment: Same!  I would love it if somebody cracks this.  Sometimes the new crash logs show up eventually. Sometimes days later.  No obvious reason.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I had the wrong operating system selected.

Make sure you have the correct OS selected for your app. In the top left of organizer is the drop down to select your app, apps are listed twice: for iOS and for Mac. If you have selected Mac (when your app is intended for iOS) crash logs won't show.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this problem after I had changed my account password. To fix:

- Go to Xcode settings -> Accounts
- See if it reports "Your session has expired. Please log in."
- Tap the button "Sign In Again..." and sign in.
- Restart Xcode.