# Xcode - Not locating crashes in project from organizer

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I am having problems with checking crash log in xcode. I have uploaded app on testflight. all crash report available on appstoreconnect. but not able to locate the logs within project repository. It works for some old crash. Some new crash report are available in organizer but, not able to locate crash in project repository. and also , For Some crash there is not option to open crash in Xcode in appstoreconnect.

Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)

MacBook Pro (Apple M1 Pro), version 13.4 (22F66)

how can I solve them?

Comment: Please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708135/xcode-isnt-showing-recent-crash-logs) might help you.

Comment: Thank you, but above  thread is not helpful to me. I am able to open the crash log in project but is not locating exact line of crashing in project.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for misinterpretation of your question. But in case if you are able to view crash then it is bit easier to locate crash by seeing stack trace in crashlytics. However if you are not able to locate it using stack trace then issue might be in third party libraries which you might be using in your project. Please try to update third party libraries if you are using in that scenario.