# App crash when relaunching from background

Tags: ios

My app sometimes crash if it has been in the background for a while and I bring it back into the foreground.  How can I debug this? Can I pull out the "console log" from the app even though it is not connected and running via Xcode?

Comment: are you run  in your app in device

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484817/how-to-get-device-console-in-xcode6