# iOS Universal Links only works for one path

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I followed the [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) to implement the **Universal Links** in our ios app. 
Our requirement is to have 3 Links/Paths that would open in the app. Everything looks correct and match the documentation, the problem is that only the first path opens the app, the others do not work at all.

Using the [Universal Links Validation](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool) Tool from Apple I can see that the link that is working pass the Universal Links validation but the links that are not working do not pass the validation.

Do you know what could be missing? Do I need to add anything else to page to enable the Universal Links?

This is how my **apple-app-site-association** files looks:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{
        "paths": [
            "/content/*", "/cars/suv/*", "/promos/"
        ],
        "appID": "78YHXXXX.com.myid.myapp"
    }]
}
}
```

The universal link **mysite.com/content/1001** works fine, but neither **mysite.com/cars/suv/1001** or **mysite.com/promos** are working.

Comment: have you add the second and third path in the apple-app-association file.

Comment: Yes, all the paths are correctly set in the apple-app-site-association file.

Comment: facing the same problem

Answer (score 6):

**Try deleting the app and reinstalling it.**

When you update the AASA file on your webserver, it does not update the cached AASA file on the device. This means that all app users will not receive the newest AASA file until they either update their apps to a new build or delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: I've tried that already. Deleted the app and installed fresh from the App Store and also tried installing from Xcode. No luck with both cases, only the first Universal Link works. Thanks for answering that, it may help someone experiencing problems with the Universal Links.

Comment: You should try checking the device logs to ensure that your AASA file is actually getting downloaded then. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484817/how-to-get-device-console-in-xcode6) Search for the domain of your AASA in the logs and if it looks like its not getting downloaded then check if your on iOS 11.2. That build has AASA issues

Comment: I checked and the file is being downloaded as expected. Still only one link is working. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For potential future readers:
I had to delete ALL apps mentionned in the apple-app-site-assiociation (not only the one I was testing universal link with)

Answer (score 5):

Ran in to the same problem today. Uninstalling the app and cleaning the build folder in Xcode resolved the issue for me

Comment: Your solution worked. This issue appeared after downloading xcode 12.0