# My app isn't getting updated when I install an updated version from crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, updating

I have an iOS app installed from crashlytics. Now I changed the name of the app but have the same provisioning profiles, when I install the app from crashlytics I get into the Waiting state into the Installing state. But after that I am stuck with a faded icon. Now tapping on the icon does nothing. I have to long press the icon and delete the app and reinstall. Reinstalling works successfully.

We really need to test the updating scenario, any idea on why our update is failing as such?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. You mentioned changing the name, do you mean change the bundle id or just the name of the app.

Comment: Just the name of the app. I double checked to make sure the bundle id remained same

Comment: Hmm, I'd double check the device logs then and see what errors are present around the install event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484817/how-to-get-device-console-in-xcode6